# How to detect an executable/file calling out a domain

Tags: malware, trace

I'm trying to trace an application/file that is calling out a domain(URL). I ran Process Monitor & Wireshark to find SVCHost.exe is responsible.

However, I'm unable to locate which file requested svchost.exe to connect over UDP.

SVC command line shows as follows:

C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService

The image path also points to the following directory.

C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

How do I find the exact file that is behind all this?P